# Problems with non-static variable inputs and trying to run methods

Tags: java

I've done a bunch research into trying to solve this issue (for about 2.5 hours), but I'm still not able to compile my program. I have tried making the method not static, but when attempting to run it, it gives me this error:

> "**Error:** Main method is not static in class prog6, please define the
>   main method as: public static void main(String[] args)"

When the main method is static, I get following error in a compiler

> **Error**: "non-static variable input cannot be referenced from a static
>   context
>             usd = input.nextDouble();"

I'm sorry if this question comes off redundant, I don't mean to ask without looking for an answer on my own, but I've been working at this for hours now and I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Some extra info on this program: it's meant to take inputs from the user to find out what currency they want to convert to, and how much USD they would like to convert. Then, I would invoke a method in order to do the calculations and return them. (Any amount trying to be converted over $200, will need 5% fee.)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class prog6
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        char curr = 0;
        double usd;
        double result;

        while (curr!='Q' || curr!='q') {   //loop

            System.out.println("What type of currency would you like to buy?");
            curr = input.next().charAt(0);

            System.out.println("How many dollars would you like to convert?");
            usd = input.nextDouble();     //asking user for info needed to convert

            if (usd>200) {
                usd = (usd)*(0.95);
            }

            result = calc (curr,usd); //invoke the method
        }
    }

    public double calc (char mCurr,double mUsd) //method
    {
        if (mCurr=='E' || mCurr=='e') {
            return (mUsd)*(0.88);
        }

        else if (mCurr=='P' || mCurr=='p') {
            return (mUsd)*(0.77);
        }

        else if (mCurr=='Y' || mCurr=='y') {
            return (mUsd)*(113.17);
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main method will need to be static. From there, create an instance of your class and call a non-static method from the static main method. eg..

```
public class Prog6 {
    private Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Prog6 prog6 = new Prog6();
        prog6.start();
    }

    public void start() {
      char curr = 0;
      double usd;
      double result;

      // etc...
    }
}
```

You could make the member variable static but it's better form to use regular non-static members and methods and call this from the static main method.

Comment: Really appreciate the help. This seemed to solve all the issues in the IDE, but I'm now getting this error:
prog6.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
        Prog6 prog6 = new Prog6();
        ^
  symbol:   class Prog6
  location: class prog6
prog6.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
        Prog6 prog6 = new Prog6();
                          ^
  symbol:   class Prog6
  location: class prog6
2 errors

Comment: I changed the class name of prog6 to upper case Prog6 as this is the way we do things in java. (the variable name should be lower case) check the case is the same for the filename and the classname.

Comment: Thanks so much, silly mistake on my part. Again, I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to solve your prolem

1. Change the `input` variable to `static`;

or

2. In `main` method, `prog6 myprog= new prog6();` and refer `input` as `myprog.input ...`.